# Two Digit next dot two digit next dot two digit two alphabets using regex in single line of text field

Tags: regex

Hi I need the digit to be displayed as follows
00.11.12aa or 00.12.55 or 11.48.61d

starts with 2 digit and decimal then 2 digit then decimal then twodigit or twodigit one alpha or twodigit two alpha.

I need to validate in single line of text field. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: @nagu, ji..konjam.. input and expected ouput ennanu sollunga...

Comment: Input text field should allow user to enter value in that field user can enter in below format only  00.11.12 or 11.55.67a or 19.36.77be. Apart from this user should not be allowed to enter anyother thing. Ithuthan requirement. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It's working

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
 Check: <input type="text" name="value" pattern="^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}$|\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}[^\d\W]{1,2}$" title="pls enter corect">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The pattern attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions 
or Safari 10 and earlier.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But this is not firing in input type text element

Comment: @Nagarajan, Naa updated pannitten..please check. This is your requirement?.

Comment: ji its not asp.net. <input type="text" id="test"/> This is my HTML element. Ithula than pattern attribute potttu update panren. But am getting nothing.

Comment: HTML element ulla athu epadi add panrathunu sollunga. Pattern attribute pottalum varala key press event ulla pottalum varala. Konjam help pannunga ji

Comment: @Nagarajan, Check this Demo New: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4QLH82T0VJY

Comment: @Nagarajan, ji what happen, I have updated the answer.

Comment: ji i stuck with another big issue didnt look at this maybe next week i have to start. Thanks for timely help. Kandipa try pannitu solren. Sure ah work agumnu nenaikiren